Можно ли использовать стриминг для отправки видео через библиотеку TeleBot?
есть вопрос. Я делал проект, в котором нужно отправить видео из стороннего сайта, и отправить его пользователю через бота в телеграме. Но можно ли использовать стриминг для этого. Так как видео больше, и скачивать видео на свой ПК и отправлять пользователю это долго. Я бы хотел чтобы пользователю отправлялось видео по частицам. Можно ли это реализовать?
